# re.sub(): I would like replace list of words following number with some string

Tags: python, regex

**want to replace text from list of words followed by number.**

```
list1 = ['apple', 'orange']
text = 'the books are good apple34'
word = re.sub(r'|'.join(list1)+[0-9],ball,text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `re.sub` should look like

```py
re.sub(rf"(?:{'|'.join(map(re.escape, list1))})\d+", 'ball', text)
```

Or, if you need whole word matching:

```py
re.sub(rf"\b(?:{'|'.join(map(re.escape, list1))})\d+\b", 'ball', text)
```

Or even

```py
re.sub(rf"(?!\B\w)(?:{'|'.join(map(re.escape, list1))})\d+\b", 'ball', text)
```

if the `list1` items can start with non-word characters.
See the [online Python demo](https://ideone.com/eS9mMG).

*Details*

- `(?!\B\w)` - a left-hand adaptive dynamic word boundary
- `(?:{'|'.join(map(re.escape, list1))})` - a non-capturing group matching one of the strings defined in `list1` (each of which is escaped with `re.escape`)
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `\b` - a word boundary.

Comment: what is different between r and rf

Comment: @sruthi `r` stops recognizing string escape sequences in the string literal. `f` allows variable expansion inside string literals.